# Activate virtualenv from python or php script not SSH

Tags: php, python, virtualenv

I am trying to activate my virtualenv using a php script or a python script but without using SSH.

This is to allow my website.com/something.py file to access certain libraries (if this can be done in another simpler way please let me know)

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
echo "A";
$result = exec("source ENV/bin/activate");

if ($result){
echo "Worked";
}
else{
echo "didnt work";
}

echo "B";
$result = system("python test.py");

?>
```

and I have test.py =

```
def main():
    print "hello"

    try:
        import xlrd
    except:
        try:
            print "xlrd didnt load"
            import MySQLdb
        except:
            print "mdb,xlrd didnt load"


main()
```

The virtualenv I have setup has xlrd installed.
This is the output I get on the webpage:

```
Adidnt workBhello xlrd didnt load
```

It makes sense that xlrd didnt load but why is the source command not working? This all works in SSH

Comment: `source` is not an executable, but a shell built-in.

Comment: well, I also tried shell_exec("source ENV/bin/activate"); and it didnt work. Either way, what command can I run to get the expected result? Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#activate-script), sourcing the `activate` script inside a shell just tweaks the `$PATH` environment variable to point to the virtualenv's `bin` directory. This script can't work from PHP, because an external executable can *never* modify the caller's environment for security reasons.

The documentation also tells you what you can do instead:

> If you directly run a script or the python interpreter from the
>   virtualenv's `bin/` directory (e.g. `path/to/env/bin/pip` or
>   `/path/to/env/bin/python script.py`) there's no need for activation.

So you can just specify the full path to the Python installation instead:

```
$result = system("ENV/bin/python test.py");
```

Comment: I tried :$result = system("ENV/bin/python test.py"); instead of $result = system("python test.py"); and Got :Adidnt workB 
When I tried it in SSH it says that ENV/bin/python isnt a file or directory but when I check it it exists

Comment: @sbeleidy: Obviously this is the same `ENV` than in your original code: `source ENV/bin/activate`. I can't know what the real path is, you have to figure that out yourself. What do you mean, you checked it and it exists?

Comment: You have this piece of code in your question: `exec("source ENV/bin/activate");` How did you figure that path out?

Comment: I put command cd ENV then cd bin then dir and I see python but when I run the entire command it says file or directory doesnt exist

Comment: @sbeleidy: You know about the difference between absolute and relative paths, right? `ENV` is a relative path. Use the absolute path instead (probably something like `/home/XYZ/ENV/bin/python`).

Comment: @sbleidy: Nice. You're invited to upvote and accept this answer ;)

Comment: I have a same issue too. So I need to activate ate environment from php.How do i do it.

Comment: i need to execute it from root folder using php from Apache web..  $op=exec('/root/Envs/ate/bin/python /var/www/cgi-bin/TStool/box_upgrade.py',$output,$return); how do I do this? I get access issues.